# I can't select an element after calling cy.get('body')

Tags: testing, conditional-statements, cypress

```
  cy.get('body'). then(body => {
      cy.wrap(body).should('have.class','.layout-header')
  }
```

cypress doesn't find the class 'layout-header'. when I do like that then it works:

```
 cy.get('body'). then(body => {
      
       cy.get('.layout-header')
  }
```

I need this because I want to use conditional testing like this:

```
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
// synchronously ask for the body's text
// and do something based on whether it includes
// another string
if ($body.text().includes('some string')) {
  // yup found it
  cy.get(...).should(...)
} else {
  // nope not here
  cy.get(...).should(...)
}
```

})
could you tell me why?, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your test `cy.wrap(body).should('have.class', '.layout-header')` is looking for a class called `.layout-header` to exist **on** the body element, not a child element **within** the body element.

I'm sure you've already read how conditional testing in [Cypress is not advised](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing), but with that in mind, this should put you on the right path to conditionally check for an elements' existence:

```
cy.get("body").then(body=>{
  // This will perform a document query on your body element and   
  // give you a static node list of child elements have the class '.layout-header'
  const hasClass = body[0].querySelectorAll(".layout-header")
  if(hasClass.length > 0)
  {
    //Code to execute if the class exists in the body
  }else{
    //Code to execute if the class DOES NOT exist in the body
  }
})
```

**Working example against a demo test site**:

```
describe("working example", ()=>{
    it("check body for elements with class name 'custom-control-label'", ()=>{
        cy.visit("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form")
        cy.get("body").then(body=>{
            const hasClass = body[0].querySelectorAll(".custom-control-label")
            if(hasClass.length > 0)
            {
                cy.log(`The class 'custom-control-label' was found in the body ${hasClass.length} times.`)
            }else{
                cy.log("The class 'custom-control-label' was NOT found in the body.")
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but that doesn't work when I want to select for example class="layout".                       <body> 
            <div .......>
                <div .....>
                  <div class="layout" >
                     .
                     .
                     .

Comment: @Ahmad would you mind providing more information please? What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'?

Comment: I mean when I write like this : const hasClass = body[0].querySelectorAll(".layout") he doesn't find the element .this means has.Class.length= 0 and I want that.

Comment: layout is a child child child element of body

Comment: It shouldn't matter how deeply nested the `layout` class element is in relation to the body, this should return all child elements having a `layout` class. Can you double check that first your initial `cy.get()` command is returning the correct element, and that the class name you're querying for is correct?

Comment: yes, cy.get(".layout") returning the correct element . but            const hasClass = body[0].querySelectorAll(".layout") it is  empty.

Comment: Two things: 1) Is it possible your element with the `layout` class isn't yet loaded when Cypress starts executing the tests? 2) Are you sure you are defining `hasClass` within the `then()` method after getting your `body` element?

Comment: thanks again for your answer . for "1" element is already loaded , because I had previously used  cy.get('.layout')  and the element is there.                                                for 2) yes I defining hasClass within then().                                                                          has this to do with the fact that the app is implemented with React ?

Comment: @Ahmad Hm, that's really bizarre. It shouldn't matter that it's a React app. I've updated my answer with a full working example against a demo site, if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: your example works for me too. the difference I saw that at the top of body is there <noscript> you need to enable JavaScript to run this app </noscript> .                   but I don't think that 's the problem right?

Comment: I mean  <noscript> was in the Code of the app in body

Comment: No. The `<noscript>` tag is meant to provide a message to users who do not have javascript enabled and has no bearing on what you're trying to do.